# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid using react-redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

Sorry for my question. I searched a lot there are many question like this but any of them is not a solution for me.

I am new in React-native. I use 2 components for my project and in both of them I use redux `connect()` function. connect() work fine in `Main.js`. but in `Todos.js` I got an error. I tried many solution Like different types of import/export but not working yet.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Main`.

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, TextInput, ScrollView, TochableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Todos} from './Todos';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addTodo} from '../actions';


class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addNewTodo = this.addNewTodo.bind(this); // Here is the key
        this.state = {
            newTodoText: ""
        };
    }

    addNewTodo(){
        var {newTodoText} = this.state;
        console.log(newTodoText);
        if (newTodoText && newTodoText != "") {
            this.setState({
                newTodoText: ""
            })
            this.props.dispatch(addTodo(newTodoText));
        }
    }
    render() {
        var renderTodos = () => {
            if (this.props.todos) {
                return this.props.todos.map((todo) => {
                    return (
                        <Todos text={todo.text} key={todo.id} id={todo.id}/>
                    );
                });
            }
        }
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"></StatusBar>
                <View style={styles.topBar}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        ToDo List
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newTodoText:text})}
                        value={this.state.newTodoText}
                        returnKeyType="done"
                        placeholder="New ToDo"
                        onSubmitEditing={this.addNewTodo}
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        style={styles.input}
                        >

                    </TextInput>
                </View>
                <ScrollView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
                    {renderTodos()}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


...

var mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    };
}
export default connect (mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

**ToDos.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, TextInput, ScrollView,TochableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {deleteTodo} from '../actions';

class Todos extends Component {
    deleteSelf() {
        this.props.dispatch(deleteTodo(this.props.id))
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <TochableOpacity onPress={this.deleteSelf} >
                <View style={styles.todoContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.todoText}>
                        {this.props.text}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TochableOpacity>
        );
    }
};

export default connect()(Todos);
```

**Note**

while I have not added `redux connect` I haven't any problem.

Comment: if `this.props.todos` is falsey then the function `renderTodos` will return undefined. you need to explicitly return `null` or `false`, or instead, write that conditional in your jsx `{this.props.todos && renderTodos}`

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine except renderTodos I'm not sure what is exact problem but you may try following. Define renderTodo in outside of render function and return null when condition will not meet.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, TextInput, ScrollViewTochableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Todos } from './Todos';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addTodo } from '../actions';


class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addNewTodo = this.addNewTodo.bind(this); // Here is the key
        this.renderTodos = this.renderTodos.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            newTodoText: ""
        };
    }


    addNewTodo() {
        var { newTodoText } = this.state;
        console.log(newTodoText);
        if (newTodoText && newTodoText != "") {
            this.setState({
                newTodoText: ""
            })
            this.props.dispatch(addTodo(newTodoText));
        }
    }
    /**
     * Define renderTodo outside in outside of render function
    */
    renderTodos() {
        if (this.props.todos) {
            return this.props.todos.map((todo) => {
                return (
                    <Todos text={todo.text} key={todo.id} id={todo.id} />
                );
            });
        }

        /**
         * return null when condition will not meet
         */
        return null;
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"></StatusBar>
                <View style={styles.topBar}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        ToDo List
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ newTodoText: text })}
                        value={this.state.newTodoText}
                        returnKeyType="done"
                        placeholder="New ToDo"
                        onSubmitEditing={this.addNewTodo}
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        style={styles.input}
                    >

                    </TextInput>
                </View>
                <ScrollView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
                    {/*Add this as now renderTodos is bind to constructor class*/}
                    {this.renderTodos()}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}




var mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```